# Is there a winning strategy in the card removal game?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, card-games, combinatorial-game-theory

A and B play a game with blue, red, and green cards. They start with an even number of $n$ blue cards ("stacks"). Player A starts, and the players take turns. Only two moves can be made:
(i) Place a red or green card on an existing stack, but the stack must not have two cards of the same color (a stack cannot have more than three cards).
(ii) If the top cards of two stacks have the same color both the stacks can be removed from the game.
The reservoir of cards is "infinite", i.e. no player can run out of cards.
The player who can't make a permissible move loses.

Can any of the players enforce a winning strategy and what would it be?

---

This is a strategy I conceived and so far it seems to work in "test games" that I ran in a spreadsheet. Not conclusive, I guess, but am I on the right track?

If $k\equiv2\mod 4$, then A can always force the victory. Otherwise, that is, $k\equiv0\mod 4$, B can force the victory. I begin by showing that if $k\equiv0\mod4$, B can force victory.

Now let $k\equiv0\mod4$. Then B can follow the following strategy to force victory. B will mentally divide the stacks into pairs of two. He will ensure during the game that the top color of each pair is always the same. If A takes away a pair, B will also take away a pair, and if A recolors a stack, B will color the corresponding "partner piece" in the same color. Thus, whenever it is A's turn, all pairs are removable. If A now takes away a pair, the total number $k$ of stacks is reduced by two, so $k\equiv2\mod4$. Thus , there must still be at least one pair that B can take away. Since the height of each stack is at most $3$, there is a finite number of moves and the game will surely come to an end. In this case, player A always leaves a number of stacks with $k\equiv2\mod4$ and B with $k\equiv0\mod4$. Thus, with this strategy, B will certainly always be able to take away the last stack and thus win.

If the game now starts with $k\equiv 2\mod 4$, A can remove $2$ stacks at the beginning. This gives B the starting position of the above strategy (a number of stacks with $k\equiv0\mod4$) and A can force the victory.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  The players only start with blue cards?  How do they get red or green cards (or can they only just play blue)?  Do the stacks exist in advance?  What is their make up?  Is there a limit to the number of stacks we can create?  If you are removing two stacks with the same color, is that your turn?

Comment: Or are you saying that the stacks are initially all just one blue card (and I guess the players have infinitely many red, green they can play)?  So if $n=2$, the first player can just remove both stacks and win instantly?  In any case, please edit for clarity.  And to show effort:  who has the winning strategy for small $n$?  What pattern can you detect?

Comment: As a suggestion: I'd ignore the constraint on parity. It seems irrelevant since even if we start with an even number of stacks we could wind up with an odd number later.

Comment: For context; what is the source of this problem?

Comment: I edited my question with a suggestion for a tentative strategy that I thought of ...

Comment: Is the source of the problem a secret? 
 (As an aside, images of text are not accessible to all readers, and can't be copied and pasted for quotes. Please replace the strategy image with the original text if you can.)

Comment: The problem was given us by our economics prof. He does that at the end of month; the problems are from everywhere, not only math. I think, it is from an old 80s Leningrad Olympiad but am not sure. I can ask him. I copied the “image” because paste & copy of text did not work and had I already typed the idea into a word-doc and did not want to write all anew. It would anyway be replaced by an answer.

Comment: @Mark: Appreciate the edit

Comment: I think your proposed strategy works, except the phrasing near the end of "player A always leaves a number of stacks with $k\equiv2\mod4$" is a little misleading since it skips past the case of A adding a card to a stack, unbalancing things but keeping $k$ a multiple of $4$. If you clarify that bit, then you could post your solution as an answer that I'd upvote.